# Increase members based on priorities

Tags: c++

I have a struct of integers and I am trying to increase them based on rules. For example, rule_1 is the max limit that the first increase should reach.

I want to change the order of additions based on priorities map (a=1,b=2,c=3), increase first "a", then "b", then "c". If I change the priorities (a=3,b=2,c=1), the additions should be made first first for "c", then "b", then "c".

I would like code review comments in terms of correct use of language and any suggestions for a better approach on this problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

struct data {
    int a;
    int b; 
    int c;
};

struct rules {
    int rule_1;
    int rule_2;
    int rule_3;
};

void set_priorities(const std::map<std::string, int>& priorities, data& d, int *&it_1, int *&it_2, int *&it_3) {

    for (const auto& p : priorities) {
        if (p.first == "a") {
            if (p.second == 1) {
                it_1 = &(d.a);
            } else if (p.second == 2) {
                it_2 = &(d.a);
            } else {
                it_3 = &(d.a);
            }
        }

        if (p.first == "b") {
            if (p.second == 1) {
                it_1 = &(d.b);
            } else if (p.second == 2) {
                it_2 = &(d.b);
            } else {
                it_3 = &(d.b);
            }
        }

        if (p.first == "c") {
            if (p.second == 1) {
                it_1 = &(d.c);
            } else if (p.second == 2) {
                it_2 = &(d.c);
            } else {
                it_3 = &(d.c);
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}

void compute_data(const std::map<std::string, int> &p, const rules r, data& d) {

    int* it_1 = nullptr;
    int* it_2 = nullptr;
    int* it_3 = nullptr;
    set_priorities(p, d, it_1, it_2, it_3);    

    do {
        if (*it_1 == r.rule_1) {
            if (*it_2 == r.rule_2) {
                if (*it_3 == r.rule_3) {    
                    return;
                } else {
                    (*it_3)++;
                    std::cout << "> > > a: " << d.a << ", b: " << d.b << ", c: " << d.c << std::endl;    
                }
            } else {
                (*it_2)++;
                std::cout << "> > a: " << d.a << ", b: " << d.b << ", c: " << d.c << std::endl;
            }
        } else {
            (*it_1)++;
            std::cout << "> a: " << d.a << ", b: " << d.b << ", c: " << d.c << std::endl;
        }
    } while (true);

    return;
}


int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> priorities;

    priorities.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("a", 1));
    priorities.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("b", 2));
    priorities.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("c", 3));

    rules r{};
    r.rule_1 = 2;
    r.rule_2 = 4;
    r.rule_3 = 6;

    data d{};

    std::cout << "a: " << d.a << ", b: " << d.b << ", c: " << d.c << std::endl;
    int repetitions = 2;

    do {
        compute_data(priorities, r, d);
        --repetitions;
    } while (repetitions > 0);

    std::cout << "a: " << d.a << ", b: " << d.b << ", c: " << d.c << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what the code does.  Can you add an example to your explanation?

Comment: @L.F. I want to increase a, b, c  up to what rules structure defines, based on the priorities being set. For example, if priorities are a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, data.a will increase up to the number defined in r.rule_1. If priorites are a = 3, b = 2, c = 1, then data.a will increase up to the number defined in r.rule_3. Hope I explained better now.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the information. Thanks!